# implementation of ping/pong for tornado websocket

Tags: python-2.7, websocket, tornado, ping

I have a `websocket client` in python implemented using `tornado.websocket.
WebSocketClientConnection`
 which connects to a server at remote end and communicate over `websocket`. Earlier I had implemented the `ping/pong` like feedback mechanism at application layer to ensure if the remote endpoint is still responsive.

I just recently updated my `tornado` package and I came across the `ping_interval` in `WebSocketClientConnection`. I removed the old `ping/pong` mechanism at application layer and added this `ping_interval` in my implementation.

After this updates the `websocket` is getting closed after the mentioned `ping_interval timeout`. The server at remote end handles the `ping` at transport layer and respond accrodingly.

1. currently I have not implemented the `ping` method so should I have to implement `ping` method for `WebSocketClientConnection`?,
2. should I have to send any data in `ping` method?
3. do I have to implement any method to handle the response send by remote server for the `ping` request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. No, [It's implemented by default](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/websocket.html#WebSocketClientConnection.ping).
2. [You may but don't have to](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.2).
3. I assume that by *response* you've ment pong. If you're using ping_interval you don't have to process pong, but if you're sending pings manually you have to control timeouts by yourself so you have to process pongs by implementing tornado.websocket.WebSocketClientConnection.on_pong method.

Comment: hi @Fian, if my server is also tornado and implements websocket using WebSocketHandler, does WebSocketHandler also have to send pong to handle the pings sent using WebSocketClientConnection?

Comment: Both WebSocketClientConnection and WebSocketHandler are based on [WebSocketProtocol13](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/485f699310d75719dddbe2b04d1c9b702f99076e/tornado/websocket.py#L622) class which does periodic pings by default and finishes connection if pong is not received in ping_interval time.